# Make a value appear first in drop down others after

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a collection of Industries that I am displaying in a drop down using this code:

```
<%= ff.select :area_of_business_id, Industry.all.map { |x| [x.name, x.id] }, {include_blank: "Select an industry"}, class: 'droplist default-droplist required' %>
```

I would like one of the specific Industries from the list to appear first in the dropdown and the rest to appear after that in alphabetical order. For example, if I have this list:

```
Airlines

Broadcasting

Chemicals

Entertainment

Insurance
```

And, I would like Entertainment to appear first, then I want the order to be changed to this:

```
Entertainment

Airlines

Broadcasting

Chemicals

Insurance
```

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes possible as below. Say you have a instance variable inside the controller:

```
@option_values = Industry.order("name <> 'Entertainment', name asc")
                         .pluck(:name, :id)
```

Now do,

```
<%= ff.select :area_of_business_id, @option_values, {include_blank: "Select an industry"}, class: 'droplist default-droplist required' %>
```

That part `order("name <> 'Entertainment', name asc")` will put the record with `name = 'Entertainment'` first, then the rest in *decreasing* order.

Answer (score 1):

Rails support priority of options out of the box for [time_zones](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select) only. In all other cases you should do it manually use something like this:

```
<% industries = [Industry.find_by(name: 'Entertainment')] + [Industry.where.not(name: 'Entertainment')] %> 
<%= ff.select :area_of_business_id, industries.map { |x| [x.name, x.id] }, {include_blank: "Select an industry"}, class: 'droplist default-droplist required' %>
```

but I recommend to add additional filed to `Industry` model for specify position in lists and sort by this filed.